# How to uninstall previous click once version programatically

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have written a Clickonce application. Now I need to find a way to uninstall the previous versions of the application when updating to a new version. This because otherwise the users need a lot of space when running the application.

Is there a way to uninstall the previous version in clickonce using source code?

Comment: If they did not improve that yet (I last checked couple of years ago) - you have to delete those folders with previous versions yourself, for example on startup of your application.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2873522